# How to remove multiple new line character from a string

Tags: regex, string, erlang

I have following string and I want remove all the '\r' and '\n' characters from this string.

Input:
    `"\r\nHi,\r\n\r\nHello read the test mail.\r\n\r\nThank you,\r\nHasitha.\r\n".`

Output: `"Hi,Hello read the test mail.Thank you,Hasitha."`

I have tried this but no luck.
`re:replace(A, "(^\\s+)|(\\s+$)", "", [global,{return,list}])`

Comment: try: "(\r?\n)+"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match `\r` or `\n`, you can simply use the pattern `\\r|\\n`:

```
1> Input = "\r\nHi,\r\n\r\nHello read the test mail.\r\n\r\nThank you,\r\nHasitha.\r\n".
"\r\nHi,\r\n\r\nHello read the test mail.\r\n\r\nThank you,\r\nHasitha.\r\n"
2> re:replace(Input, "\\r|\\n", "", [global,{return,list}]).
"Hi,Hello read the test mail.Thank you,Hasitha."
```

The pattern you used removes all the leading and trailing whitespace.